# "Command not found" when running shell script with ./

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

In Mac OSX 13, Terminal, I am trying to run a shell script, ./writeimage.sh

I cd into the folder,
I see the writeimage.sh file is there with ls -l
I see it's permissions are set correctly to 700 (rwx for me)
I use the ./ prefix because this script is not in the Path.
I stick a sudo in front, in case there is some privilege issue.

Terminal returns "sudo: writeimage.sh: command not found"

I'm out of ideas - anyone know why this is happening? What am I missing?
Thanks for any help!

```
-----MacBook-Air Downloads % ls -l
total 543176
..
..
-rwx------@ 1 lf  staff       4402 10 Mar 22:41 writeimage.sh

----Downloads % sudo writeimage.sh -d /dev/disk5s1 -i "motioneyeos-raspberrypi-20200606.img.xz"
Password:
sudo: writeimage.sh: command not found
```

Comment: Maybe try to use

sudo source writeimage.sh -d /dev/disk5s1 -i "motioneyeos-raspberrypi-20200606.img.xz"

Comment: Please post a reproducible code.

Comment: In the title of your question, you say that you run the command with `./`, but in the code you posted, you run it without providing any path.

Comment: If the script is not in your `PATH`, you need to use `sudo ./writeimage.sh`, not just `sudo writeimage.sh`.

Comment: Damn I pasted the wrong screenshot. I'm pretty certain I tried sudo ./writeimage.sh. Thanks